# Google+ updates balloon is blank in Firefox

Tags: firefox, google, gmail

In Gmail and Google+ a 1 is displayed as I have an update, but when I click on it, the balloon that shows-up is plain white and the clicks on it are transparent (i.e. they point to the links below the balloon). Is there any known fix?

Comment: Are you using AdBlock, Ghostery, or anything similar? That may be the cause. Try disabling your addons and see if it works.

Comment: You may want to check your filters. You can do that in Addons / AdBlock Plus -> Prefrences. If you are using "Fanboy's list", try "EasyList". If you are on Easylist, go with Fanboy. And so on. One will work.